# Xcode CI/CD. How to get number of test cases from command

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

So far I use slather (https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather) to do report. However, I only can get coverage rate. For test number, I have no way to get it. Anyone have ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by customising your build script and using an additional tool.

Personally if I was attempting to do this I would configure the build job to use `xcpretty` and output the build log to a file, like so:

```
xcodebuild [flags] | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty
```

When it has finished xcpretty will output something like

> Executed 84 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected)

Then just read the output from xcpretty on completion and use a regex to extract the count. Something like `^Executed (\d+) tests` should do the trick.

Useful References

- https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty (the xcpretty repo)
- https://regexr.com/ (useful for testing regex)